# How to have Average Moving Line in linear regression in vertica

Tags: linear-regression, vertica

I am new to Regression in Vertica.

I already gone through different documentation and tried to have a chart.

What i have done is,

> Created table
>
> Created Model
>
> Created Reg

```
 `SELECT LINEAR_REG('fModel', 'tablenameTraining', 'col1', 'col2'
                  USING PARAMETERS optimizer='BFGS');

  SELECT SUMMARIZE_MODEL('fModel')


  SELECT *,PREDICT_LINEAR_REG(col2 USING PARAMETERS model_name='fModel') as pred
  FROM tableTesting`
```

I am getting this chart
[image]

Now, I want one more line in my chart which will be moving average line of Blue line. It should not be constant straight line but average of every peak point.

How should I do it ?

Comment: read [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AnalyzingData/SQLAnalytics/CalculatingMovingAverage.htm) - Calculating the Moving Average

Comment: Thank for your help !! It minimizes my effort

Answer (score 1):

You just apply a plain vanilla OLAP AVG() function.
Like so:

```
   WITH predictoutput (tm,val) AS (
    -- approx form of your blue curve;
    -- minutes instead of quarters
              SELECT TIME '00:00:00' , 1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:01:00' , 2
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:02:00' , 2
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:03:00' , 0
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:04:00' , 3
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:05:00' , 1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:06:00' , 0
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:07:00' , 5
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:08:00' , 4
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:09:00' ,10
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:10:00' , 5
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:11:00' , 1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:12:00' ,14
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:13:00' , 2
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:14:00' ,10
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:15:00' , 1
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:16:00' , 0
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:17:00' ,16
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:18:00' , 5
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:19:00' ,10
    UNION ALL SELECT TIME '00:20:00' , 7
    )
    SELECT
      tm
    , (AVG(val) OVER(ORDER BY tm))::NUMERIC(9,4) AS running_avg
    FROM predictoutput
    ;
    tm      |running_avg
    00:00:00|     1.0000
    00:01:00|     1.5000
    00:02:00|     1.6667
    00:03:00|     1.2500
    00:04:00|     1.6000
    00:05:00|     1.5000
    00:06:00|     1.2857
    00:07:00|     1.7500
    00:08:00|     2.0000
    00:09:00|     2.8000
    00:10:00|     3.0000
    00:11:00|     2.8333
    00:12:00|     3.6923
    00:13:00|     3.5714
    00:14:00|     4.0000
    00:15:00|     3.8125
    00:16:00|     3.5882
    00:17:00|     4.2778
    00:18:00|     4.3158
    00:19:00|     4.6000
    00:20:00|     4.7143
```

That's all ...

Cheers -

Marco

Comment: can we do this directly when using predict_linear_reg ?

Comment: You can place your `predict_linear_reg()` into a common table expression, and apply the OLAP function outside. Let the SQL engine do what it's good at, without overloading a running function. Like so:

Comment: `WITH predictoutput as ( SELECT *,PREDICT_LINEAR_REG(col2 USING PARAMETERS model_name='fModel') as pred
  FROM tableTesting) SELECT
      tm
    , (AVG(val) OVER(ORDER BY tm))::NUMERIC(9,4) AS running_avg
    FROM predictoutput
    ;`